# What are the match and verb equivalents of resources?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, routes

In the [routing guide](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/routing.html#crud-verbs-and-actions) it says that "*a single entry in the routing file, such as `resources :photos` creates <strike>seven</strike> eight different routes in your application, all mapping to the Photos controller:*".

```
    photos GET    /photos(.:format)          photos#index
           POST   /photos(.:format)          photos#create
 new_photo GET    /photos/new(.:format)      photos#new
edit_photo GET    /photos/:id/edit(.:format) photos#edit
     photo GET    /photos/:id(.:format)      photos#show
           PATCH  /photos/:id(.:format)      photos#update
           PUT    /photos/:id(.:format)      photos#update
           DELETE /photos/:id(.:format)      photos#destroy
```

How to create the equivalent routes using `match` and the verb methods (`get`, `post`, `patch`, `put`, `delete`)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
match '/photos'          => 'photos#index',   via: :get
match '/photos'          => 'photos#create',  via: :post
match '/photos/new'      => 'photos#new',     via: :get, as: 'new_photo'
match '/photos/:id/edit' => 'photos#edit',    via: :get, as: 'edit_photo'
match '/photos/:id'      => 'photos#show',    via: :get, as: 'photo'
match '/photos/:id'      => 'photos#update',  via: :patch
match '/photos/:id'      => 'photos#update',  via: :put
match '/photos/:id'      => 'photos#destroy', via: :delete
```

and

```
get    '/photos',          to: 'photos#index'
post   '/photos',          to: 'photos#create'
get    '/photos/new',      to: 'photos#new',  as: 'new_photo'
get    '/photos/:id/edit', to: 'photos#edit', as: 'edit_photo'
get    '/photos/:id',      to: 'photos#show', as: 'photo'
patch  '/photos/:id',      to: 'photos#update'
put    '/photos/:id',      to: 'photos#update'
delete '/photos/:id',      to: 'photos#destroy'
```

Comment: Recent Rails also includes a `patch` route which is the same as the `put` one.